# Set the value of a cell when unsaved changes are detected in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to detect changes within an entire workbook (doesn't matter what changes) so that any change that occurs prior to save will result a specific cell getting set to a specific value. The goal is to show a visual indicator of whether the workbook is saved using conditional formatting (non issue, already have that set up).

The code I use to set the value of the cell is `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").Value = 1`.

I've tried to detect changes by using `Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`, but I'm unsure of how to set the range.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question as it stands is unclear.  You want to detect any changes, and capture them all, a specific change, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to setup your worksheet so that every time a change is made by a user, update the value in the cell.

You are already most of the way there, you just need to put the following subroutine in your workbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").Value = 1
End Sub
```

Once this is saved with your workbook, that specific workbook will perform the functionality you require.  Here's a link to the documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 'Target is the variable name of the Range where the Change occured
 If thisworkbook.saved=false then 
     Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").Value = 1
  else
     Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").Value = 0 'or other value
 End if
End Sub
```